# Property changes not updating in *.Designer.vb

Tags: vb.net, resx

I am using Visual Studio 2010.When grid control  back color is changed in Visual studio  it is not update in designer.vb file.

After changes designer file has

```
    Me.Axwingrid1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.Axwingrid1.Name = "Axwingrid1"
    Me.Axwingrid1.OcxState = CType(resources.GetObject("Axwingrid1.OcxState"),System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)
    Me.Axwingrid1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(160, 120)
    Me.Axwingrid1.TabIndex = 0
```

Why it is updated in .resx  and not in designe.vb file ?

Which properties of control will be stored in .resx and which property on designer.vb file.

Comment: Properties subject to localization.

Comment: Big question, no simple answer.  ActiveX controls have their own property management system, based on IPropertyBag2.  When you edit BackColor then you don't actually change Control.BackColor but manipulate the ActiveX property with that name.  Roughly, at least BackColor, Cursor, ForeColor, Font, ImeMode, Text, plus the properties that the control defines, plus a bunch of events.  Make sure that an exact answer does not matter.